# Any examples about how to use tf.nn.l2_loss in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner of tensorflow, currently I am developing a script of a learning task, in which I need to map the input image to another image, Here is my loss function:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(pred - y_)
```

where pred is my prediction of the image out of all the layers while y_ is the ground truth. The size of both of them are [batch_size * width * height * channel] ([64 x 128 x 128 x 3]). Here I simply do a substraction between these two tensors and find mean of them. As you can see this is l1 loss, but what should I do if I want to change the loss function into l2 loss? I know I should use function tf.nn.l2_loss, but the tutorial in the home page seems to be to advanced to me and don't have any examples.

Also, is there any methods in tensorflow that can return the data inside a "tensor"?

Answer (score 0):

In this case squaring the difference before doing reduce_mean should give you a squared loss, so `loss = tf.reduce_mean((pred-y_)*(pred-y_))` should do.

To inspect a tensor you can call `tensor.eval()`, but this has to happen in a context where there is enough information to compute the value of the Tensor (so all placeholders should be fed, etc).